# Why does subtracting an eigenvalue from the diagonal and solving give the eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a matrix $A$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$, why does substracting $\lambda I$ from $A$, and then solving the matrix give us the eigenspace?

Like, I don't understand the intuition behind subtracting the two, to hence obtain the eigenspace.

I can't find an answer anywhere, a high level explanation would be very much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Eigenvector by definition is the non-zero $v\in V$ such that $Av=\lambda v$ where $\lambda $ is the corressponding eigenvalue. So to find $v$: $Av=\lambda v\iff (A-\lambda I)v=0$, where $0$ is the zero matrix. In other words eigenspace associated to $\lambda$ is the $N(A-\lambda I)$.

Comment: Eigenvectors are nonzero vectors that $A-\lambda I$ sends to the zero vector. This can only happen if $\lambda$ is chosen so that $A-\lambda I$ has zero determinant (otherwise it would be invertible so it would only send the zero vector to the zero vector). That said, finding roots of the characteristic polynomial only gets you the eigenvalues, not the eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ a vector space. The eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda $ is the set $E_\lambda $ of vector $v\in V$ s.t. $$Av=\lambda v.$$
In otherword, $$E_\lambda =\{v\in V\mid Av=\lambda v\}.$$

Therefore $$v\in E_\lambda \iff Av=\lambda v\iff (A-\lambda I)v=Av-\lambda v=0$$
$$\iff v\in \ker(A-\lambda I).$$

We conclude that $$E_\lambda =\ker(A-\lambda I).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space over any field and $A$ any $(n \times n)$-Matrix acting on that space. Remember the eigenvalue equation $$Av = \lambda v$$ for $v \neq 0$. Now, rewrite $v=I v$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, and substract it from the eigenvalue equation, hence
$$(A- \lambda I )v = 0.$$ Let us assume for a moment that the matrix $A-\lambda I$ is invertible. For that we'd multiply both sides with the inverse and we'd get $v=0$. A contradiction to our requirement that $v \neq 0$. Therefore, $A-\lambda I$ cannot be invertible and so $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$. But the characteristic polyomial is exactly the determinant of $A-\lambda I$.

On the other hand, if $\lambda$ is a zero of the characteristic polynomial, i.e. $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible, $(A-\lambda I) v =0$ has a non-trivial solution and its solution is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
\begin{align*}
Av= \lambda v,~v \ne 0 
\Longleftrightarrow (A - \lambda I)v = 0,~v \ne 0 \Longleftrightarrow v \in\text{Nul}(A- \lambda I),~v \ne 0.
\end{align*}